# CLIPS. How can I check if a list of facts matching facts already given?

Tags: clips

I need to create a rule that will check if the list of facts I have entered matches the facts already given. Then the fact / facts corresponding to at least one of the entered ones are displayed.

this is what I have:

```
(deftemplate rule (multislot problem) (slot cause))
(deffacts info
(rule (problem one) (cause one1))
(rule (problem two) (cause two2))
(rule (problem three) (cause three3))
 
 (defrule reading-input
 =>
 (printout t "Enter your problems: " )
 (assert (problem (read))))

 (defrule checking-input
 (problem $?problem)
 (rule (problem $?problem1) (cause ?cause1))
 (test (eq ?problem ?problem1))
  =>
 (printout t "cause: " ?cause1 crlf))
```

how this should work:

```
CLIPS> Enter your problems: one two
CLIPS> cause: one1
       cause: two2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the read function will retrieve just one value from your input. You need to use the readline function in conjunction with the explode$ function:

```
         CLIPS (6.4 2/9/21)
CLIPS> (assert (problem (read)))
one two
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (problem (readline)))
one two
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (assert (problem (explode$ (readline))))
one two
<Fact-3>
CLIPS> (facts)
f-1     (problem one)
f-2     (problem "one two")
f-3     (problem one two)
For a total of 3 facts.
CLIPS>
```

You can then use multifield wildcards to isolate individual problems within your rule:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate rule
   (multislot problem)
   (slot cause))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts info
   (rule (problem one) (cause one1))
   (rule (problem two four) (cause two2))
   (rule (problem one three five) (cause three3)))
CLIPS>  
(defrule reading-input
   =>
   (printout t "Enter your problems: " )
   (assert (problem (explode$ (readline)))))
CLIPS> 
(defrule checking-input
   (problem $? ?problem $?)
   (rule (problem $? ?problem $?) (cause ?cause))
   =>
   (printout t "Problem: " ?problem " cause: " ?cause crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Enter your problems: one two
Problem: one cause: three3
Problem: one cause: one1
Problem: two cause: two2
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry to ask again. What needs to be changed if multi-slot "problem" will have multiple meanings?

Comment: @Nikolay I updated the example for multiple values in the problem multislot.